# Simplest possible solution to the Klein-Gordon field equation has a (KG) norm which is not constant in time

Tags: dirac-delta-distributions, klein-gordon-equation, spherical-harmonics

It is a fact that the Klein-Gordon inner product must be constant for all $t>0$, where the Klein-Gordon product is defined by
$$
\langle f, g \rangle \ := \ i \int d^3x \; \left[ f^{\ast}(t,\mathbf{x})\cdot \partial_t g(t,\mathbf{x}) - \partial_t f^{\ast}(t,\mathbf{x}) \cdot g(t,\mathbf{x}) \right] \ ,
$$
for any functions $f$ and $g$ solving the Klein-Gordon equation
$$
( - \partial_t^2 + \nabla^2 ) f(t,\mathbf{x}) \ = \ 0 \ .
$$
This can be easily verified by computing $\partial_t \langle f, g \rangle=0$ (using the Klein-Gordon equation underneath the integral and then using integration by parts).

Next, consider the following (spherically-symmetric) solution to the Klein-Gordon equation (in $3+1$ dimensions)
$$
f_{E}(t,\mathbf{x}) \ := \ e^{- i E t} \left( A \cdot \frac{\sin(E |\mathbf{x}|)}{E |\mathbf{x}|} + B \cdot \frac{\cos(E |\mathbf{x}|)}{E |\mathbf{x}|} \right)
$$
where $A,B \in \mathbb{C}$ are some unspecified integration constants and $E>0$ is some energy. It can be checked that $( - \partial_t^2 + \nabla^2 ) f_E(t,\mathbf{x}) = 0$ and therefore, we **must** have $\partial_t \langle f_E, f_{E'} \rangle = 0 $.

*However, I get a contradiction to this*. When I explicitly compute the Klein-Gordon inner product with my $f$, I find that it is time-dependent where:
$$
\langle f_E, f_{E'} \rangle = \left( |A|^2 + |B|^2 \right) \cdot 4 \pi^2  \delta(E - E') + \left( \frac{A^{\ast} B }{E'(E - E^{\prime})} -  \frac{A B^{\ast}}{E(E - E')} \right) \cdot 4 \pi e^{+ i (E-E')t}
$$
The cross-terms $\sim A B^{\ast}$ and $\sim A^{\ast} B$ are clearly time-dependent. What is going on here? I have checked this many times over and I can't see a mistake - but obviously there must be one?

**Showing my work:**

Plugging my function into the KG inner product and doing the angular integrations gives
$$
\langle f_E, f_{E'} \rangle = \frac{4 \pi( E + E' )}{E E'} e^{+ i (E-E')t} \int_0^\infty d r \;  \left( A^{\ast} \sin(E r) + B^{\ast} \cos(E r) \right) \left( A \sin(E' r) + B \cos(E' r) \right)
$$
Expanding the above yields
$$
\langle f, g \rangle = \frac{4 \pi( E + E' )}{E E'} e^{+ i (E-E')t} \bigg( |A|^2 I_1 + A^{\ast}B I_2 + AB^{\ast} I_3 + |B|^2 I_4 \bigg)
$$
where the integrals $I_j$ are defined below and can be understood as distributions (after reducing the trigonometric functions)
$$
I_1 \ := \ \int_0^\infty dr\;  \sin(E r) \sin(E' r) \ =  \ \int_0^\infty dr\; \tfrac{\cos[(E-E')r]- \cos[(E+E')r]}{2} \ = \ \frac{\pi}{2} \delta(E - E') - \frac{\pi}{2} \delta(E + E')
$$
as well as (note $\int_{0}^{\infty}dx \sin(a x) = \frac{1}{a}$ which you can surmize by looking at the Fourier transform of the Heaviside step function)
$$
I_2 \ := \ \int_0^\infty dr\;  \sin(E r) \cos(E' r) \ =  \ \int_0^\infty dr\; \tfrac{\sin[(E-E')r] + \sin[(E+E')r]}{2} \ = \ \frac{1}{2(E - E')}  + \frac{1}{2(E + E')}
$$
similarly
$$
I_3 \ := \ \int_0^\infty dr\;  \cos(E r) \sin(E' r) \ = \ \frac{1}{2(E' - E)}  + \frac{1}{2(E + E')}
$$
and
$$
I_4 \ := \ \int_0^\infty dr\;  \cos(E r) \cos(E' r) \ = \  \frac{\pi}{2} \delta(E - E') + \frac{\pi}{2} \delta(E + E') \ .
$$
We can further simplify $I_2 = \frac{E}{E^2 - E^{\prime 2}}$ and $I_3 = - \frac{E^{\prime}}{E^2 - E^{\prime 2}}$. We also note that since $E>0$ and $E'>0$ are positive the $\delta(E + E')$ don't contribute. With the above we get
$$
\langle f_E, f_{E'} \rangle = \left( |A|^2 + |B|^2 \right) \frac{2 \pi^2 ( E + E' )}{E E'} e^{+ i (E-E')t} \delta(E - E') + \left( A^{\ast} B \frac{E}{E^2 - E^{\prime 2}} - A B^{\ast} \frac{E'}{E^2 - E^{\prime 2}} \right) \frac{4 \pi( E + E' )}{E E'} e^{+ i (E-E')t}
$$
letting $E = E'$ in the terms with the $\delta$-function and simplifying the cross terms gives the quoted result.

Comment: I'm not knowledgeable about the math, but this sounds related to why the KG equation was found to be unfit to model the electron, ie. probability current was not conserved, thus prompting Dirac to formulate his version.  As I understand, it was the fact of being second-order that caused this problem, which is why the Dirac equation had to be first-order.  [See here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_equation#Making_the_Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation_relativistic)  Could that be it?

Comment: I haven't worked through the details and I'm not 100% sure this is the resolution (so maybe I shouldn't comment...), but one thing to note is that your $B$ solution $\sim \cos(|x|)/|x|$ is singular at $x=0$. Perhaps this means that solution is not in the space of test functions where the inner product is self-adjoint? In other words, maybe the integration by parts doesn't work because of the singularity at the origin?

Comment: @Andrew You might be right, and I had this same thought as well, but to counter that you can set $A =0$ right from the beginning, and all you have is the $\sim B \cos(E|x|) / |x|$ part of the solution (which is singular as you say). However, if you do this then all you have is the $|B|^2$ part of my answer in the above, which actually is time-independent. Somehow it's the cross-terms which seem to be ruining the time-independence...

Comment: I tried doing the math but gave up because of some tricky Fourier transforms. However, I suspect your solution is not actually a solution (unless $B=0$) because of the singularity. Perhaps the KG operator applied to your function gives something with delta functions, which are invisible if you just check by differentiating.

Comment: Haven't you forgot a factor of $1/r^2$ everywhere? That would make te integrals proportional to $\delta(E-E^\prime)$ which would make the exponential factor disappear. I didn't do any calculation, this is just on the top of my head.

Comment: I think Javier is right, there should be a delta function singularity if you apply the KG operator since $\nabla^2 (1/|\mathbf{r}|)=-4\pi \delta^{(3)}(\mathbf{r})$, so the $B$ function is not a solution.